# find a formula of the related combination

Tags: probability

hi guys I have a problem , I have 8 items I want to find the possible combinations I will have after eliminating each item for every stage  until i am left with 2 items. thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by stage? You need to be more specific in your question and comment what you have already tried.

Comment: I am trying to implement sequential search algorithm. so by stage I mean level, at every level i will be eliminating one item